# What proof/logic rule to use to get rid of implication

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If S is not going to the party, then K is going to. If K is going to the party, then N will too. If both K and N is at the party, then S won't go. In other words, either K but not S is at the party, or S is but K isn't at the party.

s: S is at the party

k: K is at the party

n: N is at the party

I've interpreted it as follows:$ ¬S → K, K → N, (K ∧ N) → ¬S ∴ (K ∧ ¬S) ∨ (S ∧ ¬K) $

I assumed K and got (K ∧ ¬S) from that. If I assume ¬K then I get (S∧¬K).
K →(K ∧ ¬S) or ¬K→(S∧¬K).

But what rule do I use to get rid of K or ¬K?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  What you've shown is $(S\land\lnot K)\lor(\lnot S \land K)$

Comment: Do you mean my question renders weirdly? Or do you mean that my question renders weirdly and that I've shown (S∧¬K)∨(¬S∧K)? If the latter, it seems like I have but what rule do I use to justify it?

Comment: I mean the latter.  Please use MathJax.  I'm not sure what rules you have at your disposal, so I don't know how to answer.  Basically, you have $A\longrightarrow B$ and $C\longrightarrow D$ so we can conclude $(A\lor B)\longrightarrow (C\lor D)$  In this instance though, we have $B=\lnot A$ so we know that $(A\lor B)$ is true.   Then $(C\lor D)$ is true by modus ponens (law of detachment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an informal proof you would simply say: Since $K$ or $\neg K$ is true, and since either way we wet the same conclusion, the conclusion must be true. For an informal proof this is good enough.  Indeed, this proof uses a common proof technique that is typically referred to as Proof by Cases.

However, if you want to formalize this, we'll need to know exactly with what system and rules it is supposed to be formalized.